# How do you append a button, then tell that button to remove an html element?

Tags: jquery, button

I’ve managed to successfully create an html link that, upon click, causes a message and button to appear.

I then want the appended button (and message) to disappear when the user clicks it. It’s not working and I wonder if you can help me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#link').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
            $('.div').append('<h2>Click to remove the button</h2>') .css({'background-color':'#fff'});     
                 $('.div').append('<button>Click me</button>');  
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your `dynamically` created `button` should be present when you `bind` the `click event` to it.

`.click` not works on **dynamically created elements**.

So, You must use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).on('click','button',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I’ll need to look into on() - new to me as I’m a novice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation

```
$(document).on('click','button',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

you can use

`$(buttonId).hide();`

you `hide` button and when you need it you can show it again `$(buttonId).show();`

Comment: Thanks! The fix above worked for me, but I will start looking into on() - really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is going to work, all you have to do is move the handler like so:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('div').append('<h2>Click to remove the button</h2>') .css({'background-color':'#fff'});     
    $('div').append('<button>Click me</button>');  

    // here you go ...
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/MCTNv/

The problem is that when you bind the click event`$('button').click` in your case, the button element doesn't exist yet, it gets created only after you click on the `#link`.

Comment: Argh, of course. Thanks that’s working now. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @user2699362 Make sure you accept one of the answers provided if it's whatr you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that would also work:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.div')
        .append('<h2>Click to remove the button</h2>')
        .css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    $('<button />', {
        text : 'Click me',
        click : function(){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }).appendTo('.div');
});
```